# Class "<CLASS_NAME>" nether has a main method nor its servlet specified in file web.xml

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets, netbeans

I am using NetBeans 7.1 and made a servlet in it. Now when I am running it, it is giving me

> Class ' ' neither has a main method nor its a servlet specified in web.xml

After this, it is showing me one more error:

> class ' '  does not have a main method"

I can't figure out what the problem is. I have uninstalled and installed the NetBean twice but no help. The servlet is just an ordinary servlet with no logic in it.

Comment: How are you running it? What servlet container are you using?

Comment: @DaveNewton: i am running the servet r-click on servlet and run. I am using tomcat 7

Comment: @ChandraSekhar


    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>ListDisplay</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>model.ListDisplay</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>ListDisplay</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/ListDisplay</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
</web-app>

Comment: why is it voted down....i am facing this problem

Comment: WELL I FOUND THAT IF I AM ADDING THE CONTENT TO WEB.XML THEN IT GIVES ME THIS ERROR..A

Comment: That's not a valid web.xml, please show your entire web.xml *by editing the question*. You also need to make sure you've configured your project as a web app and that you're running it as such.

Answer (score 2):

After a long search I got what I feel is the answer. Just add:

```
@WebServlet (name="name of servlet",urlPatterns={"/url patter of servlet"})
```

above your class. This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Simply restarting the NetBeans IDE will fix the bug.

Answer (score 0):

I added this to the managed beans in my project and it solve the problem. I don't know the reason though.

```
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;

@ManagedBean
```